# Checking if user owns file before deleting it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api

I'm building an API for my site that allows users to delete the files they upload. Obviously, I want to check if the user owns that file before they delete it through the API.

I have a files table and a users table, here's the schema:

```
f_id, s_id, u_id, name, size, uploaded

u_id, username, password, email, activated, activation_code
```

`u_id` is a foreign key. The `u_id` field in the files table points to the `u_id` in the users table.

Given the users username, I want to find the users `u_id`, and then check if they own the file through the file ID (`f_id`).

I wrote this SQL:

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.username
        FROM `users` u
        JOIN `files` f
        ON u.u_id = f.u_id
        WHERE f_id = ? AND u.u_id = ?
        LIMIT 1';
```

I'm assuming that'd work if I was given the users `u_id` in the API request, but alas I'm given only their username.

How can I modify that SQL to find their user ID and use that?

Thanks.

Edit: Alright I've got this query but it's always returning an empty result set even though both the file ID and username exist.

```
SELECT u.username
FROM `users` u
JOIN `files` f
ON u.u_id = f.u_id
WHERE f.f_id = ? AND u.username = ?
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: don't see what it wouldn't work. Are you sure f.u_id is correctly set? I mean does it belong to the row which has the username you're passing?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `files` AS f ON f.u_id = u.u_id AND f.f_id = ?
WHERE u.username = ?
LIMIT 1
```

I think an inner join is more appropriate in this case (might be slightly faster than left join as well)

Comment: I get this error with that query: `#1054 - Unknown column 'u.f_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Oh and also make sure you're passing the values in the same order as they are in the query. e.g. f.f_id = ? u.username = ? should be array(123, 'admin')